Centos 7 Increase CMA Size
I have a SBC module and it has Centos 7 with 3.10.0-1160.114.2.el7.x86_64 kernel version. I have to increase CMA size to 128MB which is default 4MB. I check my kernel menuconfig and DMA Contiguous Memory Allocation was enabled. I tried to way below:


Define CMA parameters: You can define CMA parameters in the /boot/grub2/grub.cfg file or other configuration files used by Grub2. These parameters are typically added to the kernel command line. An example CMA parameter looks like this:
cma=256M
This sets the CMA size to 256 megabytes.




Update Grub configuration: You can add the defined CMA parameter to the Grub configuration file using the following commands:
sudo vi /etc/default/grub



Add the CMA parameter to the GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX line. For example:
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="... cma=256M ..."



Update Grub configuration: Save and exit the configuration, then update the Grub configuration using the following command:
sudo grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg




Reboot the system: Reboot the system for the changes to take effect:
sudo reboot


After did these I check my CmaTotal with cat /proc/meminfo but it says CmaTotal 0kB and CmaFree 0kB.
How can I increase the CMA size in Centos 7?
Best regards.

1/ Check your bootlog and find (and report here) the precise boot command line actually taken into account 2/ Check your bootlog for any trace regarding that setting.

Sorry I don't know these are correct output you want but you can find outputs the link below:
https://codefile.io/f/3oLhhDzXB8
